# Relational tables from 3 CSV Files

Tags: database, relational-database

I need some help on my homework. I am asked to define the table or tables in a Relational database that are required to store the content of three CSV files.

- **NorthAmerica.csv** contains two columns (
  'Model Number',
  'number of purchases in North America'
  )
- **SouthAmerica.csv** contains two columns (
  'Model Number',
  'number of purchases in South America'
  )
- **ModelFamily.csv** contains two columns (
  'Model Number',
  'Model Family'
  )

From my understanding, I need to make the 'Model Number' the Primary Key for each table. And I believe that every item in the 'Model Number' column will map to only one item in the other 'Model Number' column, making it a one-to-one relationship. But I'm here because I'm not sure, and the resources I have looked at have given me different answers.

Note: The column 'Model Number' in **NorthAmerica.csv** might not contain all the items in 'Model Number' in **SouthAmerica.csv**, etc, and they might be in different orders as well.

Comment: This is unlear. What *exactly* are "make a relational table in a DB" & "describe the process"? Quote your assignment (as text). Give your textbook name & edition. Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Give as much solution as you can, justify it per your textbook & ask 1 clear specific question where stuck. If this is a code question then give as much of a [mre] as is relevant. PS A relational DB does not need constraints. They are so the DBMS prevents application-specific impossible states. PS Relational terms have different SQL meanings. Reference definitions.

Comment: I'm given as much as you: "1. Outline the steps to create a relational table or tables in a database 2. Describe how to get the output from above into the database. @philipxy

Comment: There is no question in your post. Also: This is to vague to answer. Using what language & libraries? Run on what operating system? Using what DBMS? Are you suposed to give SQL? Are you supposed to talk about csv input operations & intermediate data types? What level of detail? And what are you able to do? See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: "I'm given as much as you" I suspect not: I suspect you've made some guesses and assumptions and 'interpreted' what you were given, so making it harder to help you. Perhaps you're being asked to make a 'design' or a 'schema'? (That would make more sense as a question/assignment than "make a relational table ... not actually make it"). Creating tables (including their keys) uses some Data Definition Language, `relational-algebra` is for queries. SQL includes features for both data definition and queries. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question One

> 1. Outline the steps to create a relational table or tables in a database
>      [that is required to store the content of these three CSV files]

The question is actually relevant for an advanced class, say second year, after a full year of Computer Science Intro has been completed, and in a second year Relational Database unit.  Further, it would not be an introductory exercise (such as given to you), but after full lectures on the subject has been completed, as an exercise to prove competence of the delivered content.  In any other case, the exercise would be (a) unfair, and (b) clear evidence of an incompetent lecturer.

Eg. getting from the CSVs to Relational tables requires several specific technical tasks (science, including rules and methods, as well as diagrams):

1. Data Analysis
2. Relational Data Modelling

   - which includes Relational Normalisation

If you are supposed to research and learn about each of those tasks on your own, then your school is a joke.  Education is a transmittal of knowledge.  It cannot be obtained from reading, it requires the additional components of:

- trust in an authority (which is obtained by hearing), and
- personal interaction with the authority

> From my understanding, I need to make the 'Model Number' the Primary Key for each table.

Whoa.  That is step 2.7, but you do not yet understand the data (step 1).

Second, you are treating the CSV **files** as if they are tables, or ready to be converted to tables as is.  They aren't tables, they are files.  Whatever Relational tables you do create, will not be the same as the CSV files.

Third, given the lack of structure in files (CVS files included), one cannot assume that a column can be defined as a Key or Primary Key.  Files are not indexed, and thus they contain duplicate records.  They do not have the Relational concept of logical rows, they contain physical records.

- Eg. from what has been given, a `ModelNumber` may appear more than once in each file.  Depending on the platform (available methods) and the specific minor steps one chooses, making `ModelNumber` a PK may lose those records.  Just keep the CSV files as they are, and extract the records from them.
- You may choose to import them as is, into raw tables, in order to be able to use SQL to extract from them, but that is a different point.  In that case, you will not be defining any Keys on them (as explained above).

> And I believe that every item in the 'Model Number' column will map to only one item in the other 'Model Number' column, making it a one-to-one relationship.

Again, whoa.  You do not need to map one CSV file to the other, or identify relationships between them.  The task is to define the Relational tables required, not to massage or manipulate the CSV files.

In a nutshell, the task (badly specified by the lecturer) is a typical assignment (for the level I have detailed above): given such and such primitive data content (eg. Invoices and Payments; here CSV files; etc), define the Relational tables required to store that content.  It consists of:

1. Data Analysis
   understand the data that the CSV files contain.
2. Relational Data Modelling
   define the Relational tables that are required to store that data
   (not the CSV files as is).

#### Relational Data Model

I cannot give you the content or the tutorials, or the diagrams that result from each task, I can only give you the final answer.

[image: JasonTA]

- It appears the main challenge in the exercise (given that the student has been properly tutored in the science), is to determine:

  - that files; file names; and column names are not indicative of the data or the storage requirement, and
  - that the prescribed methods (above) need to be followed.
- That is, in the end, the CSVs bear little similarity to the required Relational tables.
- `Region` allows either continents such as given (eg. `North America`) or a country (eg. `Brazil`), etc.

### Question Two

> 2. Describe how to get the output from above into the database

<sub>By "output", I assume the little darling means content.</sub>

That really should be a separate question.

Further, it is not one that can be answered fully, because it is highly dependent on:

- the specific platform
- whether a genuine SQL or pretend "sql" is used
- the utilities available for each, etc.

Eg. it is simple matter to import a CSV (or other) file into Sybase; MSSQL; IBM/DB2.  Oracle is a bit more difficult.  The freeware/shareware/vapourware/noware suites (they are not real SQL and not real platforms) are hopeless.

It broad strokes, then:

- Create raw tables for the CSV files
- Import CSV files into the raw tables (so that you **can** use SQL on them)
- Use `INSERT...SELECT` to establish the Keys in the Relational tables (with `NumPurchase` being zero)
- Use `UPDATE` (which has a built-in `SELECT`) to increment `NumPurchase` from each CSV record (they are not indexed, they are not rows).

  - This method overcomes the consequences that would arise from any duplicates (multiple occurrences of `ModelNumber`) in the CSV files.

---

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH. First, for explaining things so clearly. And second, for trusting that I wasn’t “holding back” some important information that I was given. It’s my professors first time teaching and he isn’t the best at explaining things or giving directions. But yeah, thank you. This is beyond helpful.

Comment: @Jason000.  1) My pleasure.  I await your questions.  2) Teaching means explaining, and explaining **clearly**.  In that case, your "professor" should not attempt teaching.